# Train prices in Montenegro

Tags: trains, price, balkans, montenegro

Does anyone know where to find pricing and train times for trains within Montenegro, more specifically between Kolašin and Podgorica? I see train times on [The Train Line](http://www.thetrainline-europe.com/) but the site that it forwards you to has no pricing information, so I'm also wary of the validity of the times themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rome2Rio has comparison of transport prices for these two cities](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Kola%C5%A1in/Podgorica).

- Bus - $8-$45
- Train - $4 (takes 1 hour 20)
- and if you have a car, fuel is around $12-$18.

Click the details on the mode of transport on the site for further details.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't try Rome2Rio myself...

Comment: @Spr-y all good, serves as an answer for future visitors :)

Comment: Rome2Rio is a natty toy. But for serious planning it's better to search for first hand informaton.

Comment: I agree with @AndréPeseur, Rome2Rio does not provide official information.

Answer (score 5):

According to the site of the National Railway Company, a trip between Kolašin and Podgorcia costs 3.20 EUR in the second class and 4.80 in the first class.

http://www.zcg-prevoz.me/

Enter your route in the timetable search engine onm the top left of the page and you will receive a timetable and the fares.